# How to return a JSON array from sql table with PhalconPHP

Tags: phalcon

I have several tables that have JSON arrays stored within fields.

Using PHP PDO I am able to retrieve this data without issue using:

```
$query1 = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM module_settings
                WHERE project_token = ? AND module_id = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");  
$query1->execute(array($page["project_token"], 2));
$idx = $query1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$idx["settings"] = json_decode($idx["settings"]);
```

This returns a string like:
{"mid":"","module_id":"1","force_reg_enable":"1","force_reg_page_delay":"2"}

Attempting to gather the same data via PhalconPHP

```
$result = Modulesettings::findFirst( array( 
    'conditions' => 'project_token = "' . $token . '"' , 
    'columns' => 'settings' 
) );

var_dump($result);
```

Provides a result of

```
object(Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Row)#61 (1) { ["settings"]=> string(167) "{"text":"<\/a>

<\/a>
","class":""}" }
```

What do I need to do different in Phalcon to return the string as it is stored in the table?

Thank you.

Comment: `$result->settings` would return the column settings.

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 approach
First :
Get the settings with this structure :

```
$settings = $result->settings;
var_dump($settings);
```

Second :
First get array from `resultset`, then using the array element :

```
$res = $result->toArray();
var_dump($res['settings']);
```

Try it.

Comment: If so, he would not use `$idx["settings"] = json_decode($idx["settings"]);` in his eg.

Comment: Yes, but @Steven only need to get clean result, may be don't need to get decoded  json string.

Answer (score 1):

You can decode json right in your `Modulesettings` model declaration:

```
// handling result
function afterFetch() {
    $this->settings = json_decode($this->settings);
}

// saving. Can use beforeCreate+beforeSave+beforeUpdate
// or write a Json filter.
function beforeValidation() {
    $this->settings = json_encode($this->settings);
}
```